# Is multiplying y by 2^x and subtracting y faster that multiplying y by [(2^x)-1] directly?

Tags: optimization, filter, average, ieee-754, multiplication

I have a rather theoretical question:
Is multiplying y by 2^x and subtracting y faster than 
multiplying y by [(2^x)-1] directly?

`(y*(2^x) - y)` vs `(y*((2^x)-1))`

I implemented a moving average filter on some data I get from a sensor. The basic idea is that I want to average the last `2^x` values by taking the old average, multiplying that by `[(2^x)-1]`, adding the new value, and dividing again by `2^x`. But because I have to do this more than 500 times a second, I want to optimize it as much as possible.
I know that floating point numbers are represented in IEEE754 and therefore, multiplying and dividing by a power of 2 should be rather fast (basically just changing the mantissa), but how to do that most efficiently? Should I simply stick with just multiplying `((2^x)-1)`, or is multiplying by `2.0f` and subtracting y better, or could I even do that more efficiently by performing a leftshift on the mantissa? And if that is possible, how to implement that properly?
Thank you very much!

Comment: It depends on the implementation and compiler optimizations. If you want to know, benchmark it. Most likely, the difference is negligible. Is this code really a bottleneck in your application? You know what they say about premature optimization, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that multiplying a floating-point number by a power of two is faster *in practice* than a generic multiplication (though I agree that in theory it should be faster, assuming no overflow/underflow). Said otherwise, I don't think that there is a hardware optimization.

Now, I can assume that you have a modern processor, i.e. with a FMA. In this case, `(y*(2^x) - y)` is faster if performed as `fma(y,2^x,-y)` (the way you have to write the expression depends on your language and implementation): a FMA should be as fast as a multiplication in practice.

Note also that the speed may also depend on the context. For instance, I've observed on simple code that doing more work can surprisingly yield faster code! So, you need to test (on your real code, not with an arbitrary benchmark).